# PHP Download resume with hidden url link for large file

Tags: php, http

I'm sorry to bother you with my issues, but i'm facing a a problem that I have some trouble to fix.

I have a website with a login restricted area.

Once the user is logged he can access to the files of my company (big file)

But to avoid the link to be spread all over the internet when a user want to download the file, located on an external url: he clicks on a url which will contain the name of the file crypted in md5 , which redirect on a php script which is going to generate in php, headers with the download using fsockopen.

However this does not support resume of download which is not very practical when we are downloading somes files of 2 or 3 gb or when you are using a downloader.

How can I do to enable resume ? 
I have seen some php scripts using fread method , however i don't think it would be a good idea in my case, because for big files, it could make lag the server.. when you do a progressive fread on a 2gb files, good luck for the process when they are 30 poeple downloading the file in the meantime.

Comment: "when you do a progressive fread..." - when multiple people start the download at different times exactly the same thing is done ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you use `fopen()` and `fseek()` like [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php#84115), you're essentially doing the same as any Webserver does to reply HTTP-RANGE requests.

Comment: Unfortunately after some tries on a 2 gb filefor one single request using this method with a php scripti got my apache process running 23% of my CPU.. using a simple http call to the direct url of a on the same file is not even seen on process.... but maybe i'm wrong somewhere.. anyway thanks for your reply ;)

Comment: Did you try `fpassthru` after seeking?

Comment: not yet , but good ideai will try and keep you informed.. thanks for the tips :-) I did not know this function..

Comment: i tried it. It  improved a bit my CPU Process taking only 5 percent of the CPU but still comparing to a standard http download directly on the link there is a huge difference..

Comment: The load is probably due to buffering in http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_3/main/streams/streams.c#_php_stream_passthru. Have a look at http://www.coneural.org/florian/papers/04_byteserving.php. Same approach though.

Answer (score 0):

You could make it so that it doesn't allow the file to be downloaded unless they are logged in.

So instead of providing them with a direct link to the file, they get a link like foo.com/download.php?myfile.ext

And the download.php would check the session before providing the user with the file download.

Comment: Hello David,  this is what it is now but i dont know how to code in Php to provide the download with a resume support in download.php